# Replace SOH with space in MAC

Tags: macos, bash, python-2.7, sed

I have a file, when opened with sublime text has some SOH characters.

I am trying to replace this SOH characters with space.

I tried Python, and sed commands but none of them are working.

```
cat -v small.txt | sed 's/'001'/ /g' > out.txt
```

It replaces it with ^A.

Here is python code as well.

```
escapes = ''.join([chr(char) for char in range(1, 32)])

for f in file_in:

    t = f.translate(None, escapes)
    print(t)
```

What is the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `cat -v`? That will indeed replace all non-printable characters with a textual representation (...such as `^A`). Did you try to run the command *without* the `sed` ;-) That would have shown what was going on and that `s/'001'/ /g'` was wrong ;-)

In any case, there is no need for a `cat` here:

```
sed $'s/\x01/ /g' file.txt
```

The `$` tells the `bash` shell to interpret escape codes in this string, such as `\x01`.

And in Python it works pretty much the same:

```
>>> 'Hello\x01World.'.replace('\x01', ' ')
```

I'm not sure what you expected `f.translate(None, escapes)` to do? That looks like random trial-and-error code and isn't how `translate()` works at all ;-)